# Android detect when user clicks on a e-mail in a webview

Tags: android, email, android-intent, webview

I have an app with a custom built e-mail client functionality. The e-mail body is shown in a webview.
If there is an e-mail address in the body of a e-mail, then the webview detects it and makes it clickable. When the user would click on the e-mail address, then Android shows a prompt asking which e-mail app the user would like to open.

Is it possible to catch it when my app tries to open a e-mail intent/app? I would like to open my own Activity for it.

Comment: that mean you want to show your app list in mail app on click email ?

Comment: No, I want that if the user clicks inside my app onto a e-mail link, that I can handle it by showing my own activity for it in place of opening a e-mail app.

Comment: so you have to handle this event in only for your app no other one?

Comment: This has nothing to do outside the app. Inside my app there is a Webview which could contain e-mail addresses. If the user clicks on it. Android tries to open a E-mail app. I would like to prevent this and handle this my own. So if the user clicks on a e-mail, i would like to execute my method like this: handleEmailLink(Bundle bundle)

Comment: that for you have to use deeplinking that can be you can do this

Comment: I was thinking about it and I think  I am going to add my app to the e-mail app list like you suggested it. My app could support sending e-mails from outside the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have thought about it and decided to make my app support sending e-mails. So if  the user tries to start an e-mail intent to send mails, my app is also shown now as an e-mail app.

Thanks to @Ravi to bring me on this idea.

I have used this intent filter:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
        <data android:scheme="mailto"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/realworks_email_opstellen">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/realworks_email_opstellen">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
        <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

add below intent filter in your manifest to make it work.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
               android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: This doesn't work and I think this is not the correct solution. Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Programatically it is possible to override the shouldOverrideUrlLoading function.

```
override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean
```

And then check if the user clicked on a mailto link:

```
if(url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
    println("MAIL CLICKED INSIDE WEBVIEW")   
  }
```